# SELECT from TWO tables without some records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have TWO tables:

```
t1 contain ID_car (unique), name 
t2 contain ID_car(from t1), status (many status records on same ID_car)
```

And i need the following result:

```
All ID_car FROM t1 WITHOUT status = something
```

I already try it INNER, LEFT, RIGHT JOIN and didn't work.
How can i do that?
Many thanks for help!

More details:

```
t1
------------
ID_car      name
------------------
1           Toyota
2           Honda
3           Mazda
4           Ford


t2
-----------------
ID_car      status
1           ok
1           not_ok
2           ok
4           not_ok
```

ID_car 3 din not have any records in t2 but i want to display result

And i need the following result (all car from t1 without car status not_ok):

```
the expected result
-----------------
ID_car      status
2           ok
3
```

---

Update 2
Finally solved! Thanks for help!
That's works for me:

```
    SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE t1.ID_auto NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID_auto FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.ID_auto = t2.ID_auto AND t2.category='not_ok')
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: One question: if on t2 exists a row with **status = "something"** and another row with **status != "something"** should the ID of this car be on the expected output or not?

Comment: Try NOT EXISTS.

Comment: "I already try it ..."  So where's one of those tries???

Comment: I've edit my ad because the code in comment section is unclear.

Comment: @D.Smania Should not to be output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- updated per comment below.  This update will return all records from T2 (even if not existing in T1) but only if T2.Status != something

-- this should do what you want.  It will give you all the records in T1, and any data in T2 (but not required to be in that table)  where your T1.status is not something

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
-- did the logic on the JOIN here instead of in where clause, because doing in where clause would force records to appear in t2 table (basically converting it to an inner join) doing it in the join itself does not cause this to happen
AND T2.Status != 'something'
```

Comment: the status column should be in t2.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ID_car
   FROM t1
   LEFT JOIN t2
     ON t1.ID_car=t2.ID_car
  WHERE t2.status=something
```

Comment: Similar to mine but I think he said WITHOUT  for the status is something?  Or I misread what he was asking

Comment: @Brad I think the author was not being 100% clear. I understand it as he asked for records without status of "something".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_car
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN
     t2 on t1.ID_car=t2.ID_car
WHERE NOT t2.status='something'
```

Created from top of my head, hopefully it works!

Maybe if you could post the queries you wrote, maybe they could show us why the joins don't work because it should.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand correctly but try and let me know:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID_car FROM t2  INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.ID_car = t1.ID_car WHERE t2.status != 'something'
```